# Start Time of Page Load in Page Timings in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, performance, load-time

What's the start event for the 'Page Load Time' in the 'Page Timings' report?

I've read that GA uses NavigationTiming API. Is it v1? Is the start event `performance.timing.navigationStart`? Also, what's the end event? Is it `domLoaded`?

The reason for my question is that we've implemented page load metrics with custom code and User Timings. That's to ensure that we measure time till we finish all additional XHR requests and a user can interact with a page. Our start time was `navigationStart`.

However, we've noticed problem with that. We have a Single-Page Application where even if the URL changes in the browser, it's done via the `history` API, as a result the output of `performance.timing` doesn't change when you go from one page to another. Hence, the load time could be artificially high for some pages, since `navigationStart` will indicate the moment the browser went to the web app, as opposed to specific page.